# Enums With Default Throw Clause?

Tags: java, enums, java-5

I noticed the following in the Java Language spec in the section on enumerations here: [link](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)

```
switch(this) {
  case PLUS:   return x + y;
  case MINUS:  return x - y;
  case TIMES:  return x * y;
  case DIVIDE: return x / y;
}
throw new AssertionError("Unknown op: " + this);
```

However, looking at the switch statement definition section, I didn't notice this particular syntax (the associated throw statement) anywhere.

Can I use this sort of "default case is throw an exception" syntactic sugar outside of enum definitions?  Does it have any special name?  Is this considered a good/bad practice for short-cutting this behavior of "anything not in the list throws an exception"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I get you, but you seem to believe that the `throw` is part of the `switch` syntax in the posted code sample. That is not the case. The `switch` block and the `throw` statement are two seperate things, which just happens to be placed next to each other in this code.

In more detail: The four `case` parts in the `switch` all contain `return` statements, causing any subsequent instructions in the method to be skipped. If none of the `case` parts matches, execution continues on the line following the `switch` block, which happens to be a `throw`.

You could use a `throw` after an `if` in a very similar way:

```
if (something) {
    return aValue;
}

throw new Exception("Nope");
```

Comment: Thank you.  I completely missed the return statement in each case when I first looked at the code.

Answer (score 3):

Shame on the writer of that tutorial for throwing an AssertionError - why not make use of the Exceptions that Java provides us already, like [UnsupportedOperationException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

Comment: Surely the tutorial refers to java.lang.AssertionError.

Comment: @phloser An error is supposed to indicate that you cannot recover from the problem. This seems like something you could recover from.

Comment: In that particular example, where the enum has four possible values, and a method on the enum accounts for all four values in a switch on 'this', I'd be very interested to hear how one might recover.

I find myself raising AssertionError in circumstances that really ought never happen. Superior to using assert statements, IMHO, in that such assertions can be turned off. I'd rather the app fail spectacularly and loudly if such a condition has been violated.

I'm not sure that exceptions such as UnsupportedOperationException and IllegalStateException are intended to be recovered from.

Comment: @phloser it's very possible to recover from that. The typical use case for this type of mistake would be when someone adds a new operator, for example `% modulo` and forgets to change this particular switch statement to add it. Would you really want to throw an assertion error if this went live? Absolutely not! You'd want to gracefully tell the user "I'm sorry, but modulo is not supported with this operation." And let them try another operation.

Comment: In your modulo example -- I'd let it fail spectacularly. Attempting to catch and react to UnsupportedOperationException, IllegalStateException, or other unchecked exceptions, to me, smacks of attempting to cover up programmer error. But that's just me.

Comment: Yes, it does cover up programmer error. It says "Look, we made a mistake. A junior programmer added this four years after it was written and he didn't add/test everything. We're sorry it went live, but at least we didn't bring down your production servers because it failed. Instead, we recovered from the exception, you reported it, and now a fix is forthcoming." Same result as 'failing spectacularly' except there's no further downtime for the client.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `default` keyword:

```
switch (whatever) {
  // ...
  default: explode();
}
```

If you want the default case to throw an exception, then

```
  default: throw new Explode();
```

Your example only works the way it does because all the other branches return from the containing function. **In my opinion that's not a very good coding habit to get into.**

Comment: I think explaining that it means you get an exception at run time rather than a 'missing return' compiler error would be better than shouting.

Comment: Well I didn't mean to shout at anybody, I was just being emphatic. Often on SO I find myself giving direct answers to questions, and then having to back out and clarify that I think the entire undertaking is a mistake. In this case, I wanted to emphasize that beyond the inherent "code smell" of a `switch` in the first place, that multi-way "return" dispatch is something I'd avoid.  It's a matter of opinion of course.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, if you do not cover all enum values in a switch statement it generates a warning at compile time.

If, however, you put a `default:` case that warning does not work anymore.  So, yes in some IDEs there is a definite advantage of omitting `default` case when all enum values are covered in a switch statement.

In general, if your switch statement grows beyond 5-6 cases, consider redesigning the code.  Usually, people do not appreciate that enums in Java are full blown classes and enum values are first-class objects, so instead of driving the behavior through the switch statement in many cases you can ask the enum object to do the work itself.

In this particular example the enum can have a method `doOp( int x, int y)` and each enum member can implement a particular flavor of this method.

Comment: It should be noted that Enum values will only become full blown classes iff the value has a related class body (even if that body is empty {}). Otherwise they will be instances of the Enum class. If you can mimic polymorphism with a switch, and thus avoid declaring the method abstract, you will have fewer classes to load, which may or may not get you anything.

Comment: @ILMTitan: Not true. Even enums with value declarations only are the classes in their own right.  They are definitely the descendants of java.lang.Enum, but classes nevertheless.

Comment: enum BoolEnum {TRUE(true), FALSE(false){//class-like body}; //contstructors etc.}. BoolEnum will always be its own class. However, because FALSE has a body, its class will be BoolEnum$1, while true's class will just be BoolEnum.

Comment: @ILMTitan: Agree to that.  But in your first post you said instances of `Enum` class, and that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this is not syntax sugar. It works because all of the branches on the switch return from the method. If some other enum value was put into the switch, the switch statement would complete without running any of the branches, after which the throw statement would execute.

```
switch(this) {
  case PLUS:   return x + y;
  case MINUS:  return x - y;
  case TIMES:  return x * y;
  case DIVIDE: return x / y;
  default: throw new AssertionError("Unknown op: " + this);
}
```

That code would be functionally equivalent. The major difference between the two is that your switch with no default clause will create a compiler warning if a value is added to the Enum but not to the switch statement.